# Look for string inside of other string and print location in C

Tags: c, string

I am trying to search for a string inside of another string ("arm" in, say, "karma").

If there is a match, I am to print `FOUND at (index)` to the console (the "index" here being how many letters in, starting from 0).

Otherwise, I am to print `NOT FOUND`. Right now, the console takes both of the inputs but then quits. This is what I've got so far:

```
int main() 
{
    char string1[10];
    char string2[10];

    printf("Write first string:  ");
    scanf("%s", string1);
    printf("Write second string:  ");
    scanf("%s", string2);

    for (int i = 0; string1[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        if (string1[i] == string2[0]) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; string2[j] == string1[i + j]; j++)
            {
                if (string2 == '\0') 
                {
                    printf("FOUND at %d", i);
                }
            }
        }

        if (string1[i] == '\0')
        {
            printf("NOT FOUND");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I apologize in advance for the lack of subroutines. I'm super, super new to all of this.

Comment: Is there some reason you're not permitted to use standard library functions? If so, then please say so.

Comment: Any reason not to use C library functions from `string.h` like `strstr`?

Comment: I'm guessing he got this as an assignment ("I am to ..."), so library functions are probably cheating. He did make an effort and shown his code though, so his question seems legit.

Answer (score 4):

`strstr()` will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Your `NOT FOUND` condition will never be met, if `string1[i] != 0` you exit the outer loop without printing anything.
If you move that check outside the external loop (you'll need to define `i` before the loop for that, in the function context), you'll be able to hit it.

Also, you `FOUND` case should break out of the external loop (note that a simple `break` is not enough), otherwise you'll also hit the `NOT FOUND` case

Comment: @CRD What is an OP.  I haven't figured that out yet.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey - Original Poster as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use `strstr()`?

Example:

```
char *str = "karma";
char *pChPos;

pChPos = strstr(str, "arm");

if(pChPos)
    printf("Found \"arm\" at position %td\n", pChPos - str);
else
    printf("Didn't find it!\n");
```